# Form validation when form spans multiple tabs

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I have a form that spans multiple tabs in a TabStrip control.  However, when the form is validated (e.g. f.valid), not all controls are considered when the validation is evaluated.

For example, if an input field is on tab 1 that is marked as "required" and the save action is called when the focus is on tab #3, the form will read as invalid since the required field is not in view.  If the focus is on Tab #1, all works as expected.

I understand why this behavior is occurring, but I wanted to see if there was any suggested workaround.

Thanks!

**Update**

I created a plunkr that shows the basic issue.  It is actually a little backwards from the problem I described, but it shows how the form ignores the fields on tabs other than the one displayed during validation: [Plunkr Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/7Gs5vS1rcpG3VBSEpSfR?p=preview)

The template code looks like this:

```
  <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(f)">
  <kendo-tabstrip>
    <kendo-tabstrip-tab [title]="'Paris'" [selected]="true">
      <ng-template kendoTabContent>
        <input type="text" name="controlOne" id="controlOne" [(ngModel)]="myModel.controlOne" required>
      </ng-template>
    </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
    <kendo-tabstrip-tab [title]="'New York City'">
      <ng-template kendoTabContent>
        <input type="text" name="controlTwo" id="controlTwo" [(ngModel)]="myModel.controlTwo">
      </ng-template>
    </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
    <kendo-tabstrip-tab [title]="'Tallinn'">
      <ng-template kendoTabContent>
        <input type="text" name="controlThree" id="controlThree" [(ngModel)]="myModel.controlThree">
      </ng-template>
    </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
  </kendo-tabstrip>
  <button type="submit">Save changes</button>
</form>
<div>
  Valid when saving: {{ isValid }}
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using Reactive forms or template?  If you are using Reactive forms, make sure each control shares the same form group, or else if they have separate form groups in each tab, make sure the groups share the same parent.  Perhaps paste your markup and form create code

Comment: It is using template driven forms.  Updated question to show an example.